# Display image as a popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, core-animation

I want to display an image upon `UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft`. How can I display image as a popover upon button click?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that a popover screen will open with an image inside it.
This is how to do it, just add an image programmatically to the popover view, or better still, add the image directly in interface builder to MyPopOverView XIB

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender
{
    if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    myPopOver = [[MyPopOverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopOverView" bundle:nil];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myPopOver] ;

     // THE IMAGE
    UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"popoverImage.png"]];

    [popoverController addsubview:icon];

    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350.0f, 500.0f)];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    } else {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: [popoverController addsubview:icon]; i can not add subview to the popover controller

Comment: try adding it via Interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Use custom popOverViewController Like WEPopOverController. It contains some property to change the pop over arrow image etc.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wepopover

```
- (WEPopoverContainerViewProperties *)defaultContainerViewProperties {
    WEPopoverContainerViewProperties *ret = [[WEPopoverContainerViewProperties new] autorelease];

    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(30.0f, 30.0f);
    NSString *bgImageName = @"tri123.png";//@"round-rect-box.png";
    CGFloat bgMargin = 2.0;
    CGFloat contentMargin = 2.0;

    ret.leftBgMargin = bgMargin;
    ret.rightBgMargin = bgMargin;
    ret.topBgMargin = bgMargin;
    ret.bottomBgMargin = bgMargin;
    ret.leftBgCapSize = imageSize.width/2;
    ret.topBgCapSize = imageSize.height/2;
    ret.bgImageName = bgImageName;
    ret.leftContentMargin = contentMargin;
    ret.rightContentMargin = contentMargin;
    ret.topContentMargin = contentMargin;
    ret.bottomContentMargin = contentMargin;
    ret.arrowMargin = 1.0;
    ret.upArrowImageName = @"popoverArrowUpSimple.png";
    ret.downArrowImageName = @"tri2.png";   // Customize your Image
    ret.leftArrowImageName = @"popoverArrowLeftSimple.png";
    ret.rightArrowImageName = @"popoverArrowRightSimple.png";
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fulfil this scenario is to make a custom uiview according to your demands, and set an image in it which you want to show as popover. and make it appear when you want to show your popover.